# BBEdit 13: Extract function within Text Factory

Tags: grep, bbedit

New to Text Factories here in BBEdit 13.

I know how to press the EXTRACT button in the Find and Replace window but can't figure out how to include an Extract as one of the steps within a Text Factory.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with BBEdit 13.1, this can be done in text factories using the "Delete Non-Matching Text" step. Borrowing from the change notes:

```
This operation works similarly to using the Extract button
in the Find window; but rather than creating a new document with
the extracted text, the document's contents are **replaced** with
the results.

Thus, using this operation will delete any text which was **not**
matched by the search string (or pattern), and the remaining text in
the document will consist of all matches of the search string (or
pattern), separated by line breaks. As with the Extract operation,
this is not terribly useful for literal matches, but quite powerful
when using Grep and a suitable replacement pattern.
```